# Locking rows in in innoDB for multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I was looking at row locking for innoDB and it seems like `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` is the go to query for locking. In my file I have three queries. Two updates and then an insertion. Is there a way to make sure that for each connection the rows are locked and then these three queries can run before someone else can change the rows?

Here are the queries:

```
"UPDATE table SET r=r+2 WHERE r > '$l' AND home='$home'";

"UPDATE table SET l=l+2 WHERE l > '$l' AND home='$home'";

"INSERT INTO table (value, home, l, r, value2)
            VALUES ('$value', '$home', '$l'+1, '$l'+2, value2) ";
```

To clarify: I want to lock all the rows where home=$home and then free them after the three queries. I want to make sure the three queries are executed before any other connections can have write abilities to those rows.

Comment: You can't lock a row that isn't there. So there is no way you can lock all "three" rows. You can only lock the two rows that you `UPDATE`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah I guess I kind of made it sound like that. I meant locking all the rows where home=$home and then freeing them after the three queries are done. So if there was something like `LOCK UNTIL FREE` and then after the queries `FREE`.

Comment: Rows that you UPDATE will be locked until you commit. So if the UPDATE is the first thing you do, that's all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use transactions, your changes are not visible to others until you commit them explicitly.

Further informations: [msql docs on transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html)